# Send a string value from Activity to Fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I need to pass a String from an Activity to a fragment but nothing seems to work for me.

I found this answer on stackoverflow

> From Activity you send data with intent as:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putString("edttext", "From
Activity"); // set Fragmentclass Arguments Fragmentclass fragobj = new
Fragmentclass(); fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

> and in Fragment onCreateView method:

```
 @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup
 container,
         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     String strtext = getArguments().getString("edttext");    
     return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false); }
```

But this doesn't work for me. When I click the button nothing happens.

*Is it maybe because the fragment is already created?* In my app: ToDoFragment> Activity(pass data to:>ToDoFragment

Here is my code but I don't thing it will provide more info:

**Activity.java** (inside OnClickListener of a button)

```
        String datePassed = mDate.getText().toString();
        String toDoPassed = mEditText.getText().toString();

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key1", datePassed);
        //set Fragmentclass Arguments
        ToDoFragment myToDoFragment=new ToDoFragment();
        myToDoFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

**ToDoFragment.java** (inside oncreateview)

```
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
if (bundle != null) {
    mToDoInfo = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(key1);
```

Comment: strange you are initiating the bundle but not getting stringExtra from it instead you are calling it from the scope of fragment parents activity which is why its not working

Comment: where you defining you Fragment class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correct, then you are not doing it wrong, but you are doing this in **wrong** scenario. This is on assumption that your fragment is already inflated & you are starting new Activity from it & want the data **back** as result from it. so what you need is something like this,

inside your `ToDoFragment` where I believe you are starting activity, do this instead:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), MyActivity.class), 1001);
```

& override `onActivityResult` method like:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode == 1001 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String myData = data.getStringExtra("my_key");
        }
    }
```

& now inside onClick of your `MyActivity`,

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("my_key", "my_data");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

this should invoke `onActivityResult` of fragment where we wrote code to get data.

Comment: Yes! That's what I needed. I didn't know about the existence of startactivityforresult. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is because the fragment is already created. Create a method in your fragment class and call it from inside the `onClick` method of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

Let me make it Easy for you!

```
ToDoFragment myToDoFragment=new ToDoFragment(datePassed); //easy right?
```

and in your `ToDoFragment` class make a constructor with String as input!

Comment: I don't know why but android gives warning when we create parameterized constructor in fragments.

Comment: try to run it will execute

Comment: I'm not the one who asked the question. :D

Comment: As  sam_0829 pointed, all the ways I was trying weren't working because I was using a wrong scenario, the fragment was already created.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply follow this pattern to pass the values from activity to fragment

**ToDoFragment.java**

```
 public class ToDoFragment extends Fragment {

    String date;

    public static Fragment newInstance(String date) {
        ToDoFragment fragment = new ToDoFragment();

        fragment.date = date;

        return ToDoFragment;
    }
}
```

In your **activity's onclick**

```
String toDoPassed = mEditText.getText().toString();
ToDoFragment myToDoFragment = ToDoFragment.newInstance(toDoPassed);
```

Comment: why repeated answer?

Comment: I don't think this is repeated answer.